# Strategy for data handling/custom colors in ShaderMaterial

Tags: colors, 3d, three.js, webgl, shader

I need strategic help to get going.
I need to animate a large network of `THREE.LineSegments` (about 150k segments, static) with custom (vertex) colors (RGBA). For each segment, I have 24 measured values over 7 days
[so `5.04 × 10^7` measured values, or `2.016 × 10^8` `vec4` color buffer array size, about 770Mb in `float32array` size].
The animation is going through each hour for each day in 2.5 second steps and needs to apply an interpolated color to each segment on a per-frame-basis (via time `delta`). To be able to apply an alpha value to the vertex colors I need to use a `THREE.ShaderMaterial` with a `vec4` color attribute.
What I don´t get my head around is how to best handle that amount of data per vertex. Some ideas are to

- calculate the RGBA values in render loop (between current color array and the one for the coming hour via interpolation with a time `delta`) and update the `color` buffer attribute
  [I expect a massive drop in framerate]
- have a `currentColor` and `nextColor` buffer attribute (current hour and next hour), upload both anew in every step (2.5 sec) to the GPU and do the interpolation in the shader (with aditional time `delta` uniform)
  [seems the best option to me]
- upload *all* data to the GPU initially, either with multiple custom attributes or one *very* large buffer array, and do the iteration and interpolation in the shader
  [might be even better *if* possible; I know I can set the offset for the buffer array to read in for each vertex, but not sure if that works as I think it does...]
- do something in between, like upload the data for one day in a chunk instead of either all data or hourly data

Do the scenario and the ideas make sense? If so:

- **What would be the most suitable way of doing this?**
- I appreciate any additional advice.

Comment: Is it that much work to try them all? Personally I'd probably try "upload all data" whether it's in a buffer or a texture.

Comment: okay, thanks @gman...yes I will try different sized chunks and see where it goes. I was hoping for an established method; it doesn't come as easy to me getting the right idea about doing things in three.js/webgl with buffer attributes.